# How to set shared Preferences to show custom animation on first launch?

Tags: android, animation, sharedpreferences

I'm a beginner to android programming. I'm not clear about the concept of shared preferences.
I need to set a particular animation on the first launch of the app(fragment from fragment activity) and for the consecutive launches of app(minimizing) another animation. So how can I utilize the shared preference to do so?

Comment: You should utilize [`onPause()` and `onResume()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) methods instead of using SharedPreferences. If you don't need to keep information about the app AFTER it has been *destroyed*, then you can just use a regular variable anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    SharedPreferences prefs = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Perhaps set content view here

        prefs = getSharedPreferences("key", MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (prefs.getBoolean("firstrun", true)) {
            prefs.edit().putBoolean("firstrun", false).commit();
            // here comes your animation for first start
        }
        // here comes your animation for other starts
    }
}
```

Comment: nice. im glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) documentation at [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com)

Have a look at these links:

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/content/android-sharedpreferences-example/

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFileBasedPersistence/article.html

http://rajeshvijayakumar.blogspot.in/2013/03/shared-preferences-example-in-android.html

http://androiddeveloperspot.blogspot.in/2013/01/sharedpreference-in-android.html

http://alchemiaandroid.altervista.org/sharedPreferencesTutorial.html

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/

http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/shared-preferences-example-in-android-programming/

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/android-preferences-activity-example/

Answer (score 0):

For animations use this

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.no_anim, R.anim.slide_to_top);
```

to create animations create "anim" folder in "res" and create slide_left.xml like following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="200"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="-100%" />

    <alpha
        android:duration="200"
        android:fromAlpha="1"
        android:toAlpha="0" />

</set>
```

Comment: This does not answer his question.